# Rails: How to pass parameters from a model using an after_commit method, eventually to share on twitter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, parameter-passing

I'm trying to use an after_commit method to pass parameters from the post to the user model where it is shared to twitter with another method.

It works fine when I just pass it something from the post model like 'title' or 'content':

#### post.rb

```
after_commit :share_all

def share_all
 if user.authentications.where(:provider => 'twitter').any?
    user.twitter_share(title, content)
 end
end
```

#### user.rb

```
def twitter_share(title, content) 
  twitter.update("#{title}, #{content}")
end
```

But this is as far as my understanding goes, I've read elsewhere that I could pass 'self' instead of 'title' and 'content', and still be able to use 'title' and 'content' plus any thing else from the model such as 'created_at'. However, I can't seem to get this working, I've tried this :

#### post.rb

```
def share_all
 if user.authentications.where(:provider => 'twitter').any?
    user.twitter_share(self)
 end
end
```

#### user.rb

```
def twitter_share(self) 
  twitter.update("#{title}, #{content}")
end
```

And I get SyntaxError (/Users/ihal/Desktop/dayor/app/models/user.rb:118: syntax error, unexpected keyword_self, expecting ')'
def twitter_share(self)

And it posts this to twitter #< Post:0x00000101d6e1e0>

My question is how to you properly setup passing 'self' so that any parameter could be called with twitter.update()?

Also how do you go about pulling out URL for the post, so that you could pass the URL to share on twitter?

Edit:

## trying Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.post_url(@post, :host => 'myhost.com')

### in post.rb

```
 class Post < ActiveRecord::Base  # line 19

 after_commit :share_all

 Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.post_url(@post, :host => 'myhost.com')    #line 37

 def share_all
 if user.authentications.where(:provider => 'twitter').any?
    user.twitter_share(self)
 end
end
```

When I go to delete a post, I get the error :

Started POST "/posts/32" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-04-15 14:57:17 -0700
  Processing by PostsController#destroy as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"x8KkqLLCLdTOouUfCMzyWWmwxLIKThnE1n3rQNSkew8=", "id"=>"32"}
  User Load (1.1ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE ("users"."id" = 5) LIMIT 1
Completed   in 82ms

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"posts"}):
  app/models/post.rb:37:in `<class:Post>'
  app/models/post.rb:19:in`'
  app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:36:in `authorized_user'

Rendered /Users/ihal/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@rails3gemset/gems/actionpack-3.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.erb within rescues/layout (1.2ms)

### post controller

```
def destroy
  @post.destroy
  redirect_to root_path
end


private
   def authorized_user
   @post = Post.find(params[:id])   #line 36
     redirect_to root_path unless current_user?(@spost.user)
   end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what I can see in code is, title and content are attributes of Post. so passing them as theire name will be converted into their value.

now you are passing self in twitter_share from post then the post object will be passed to that method. you need to modified the twitter_share method as below to make it work

```
def twitter_share(post)
 twitter.update("#{post.title}, #{post.content}")
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you thought about using an [Observer](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#observers)?  That way you can keep the after_commit stuff, which does not appear to to belong in the model, in its proper place.  Plus it helps simplify your model instead of cluttering it up.

For the syntax error, `self` is a reserved word.  Rename the variable name in the method declaration.  So try something like:

```
def twitter_share(post)
  # do stuff
end
```

To access the url helpers outside of the controller, use:

```
Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.post_url(@post, :host => 'myhost.com')
```

Don't forget to use the :host option when accessing the url helpers outside the controller so the helper has context.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. I am trying to get the code above working  but am running into some problems, namely when I add the Rails.application.routes... my destroy action fails and says there's no route. I've edit above to show whats happening.

Comment: `Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.post_url(@post, :host => 'myhost.com'` returns the url to the post specified by `@post` as a string.  That should go inside the method where you need the url.  My guess is inside twitter_share.

Comment: Hmm im still getting the error No route matches {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"posts"} when using the Rails.applications.routes.url_helpers code, any ideas?

Comment: what does routes.rb look like?  Make sure it contains a line that reads `resources :posts` or that you manually specified the route to delete a post.  If you make any changes you will have to restart the rails server.

Comment: I have  resources :supportposts,  :only => [:create, :destroy, :index, :show] in my routes.rb and everything with deleting posts works fine when I remove the Rails.applications.routes.url.. code, and when i run rake routes I have this route post DELETE /posts/:id(.:format)         {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"posts"} Im pretty perplexed

Comment: Do you have both supportposts and posts?

Comment: What is :id => the_post_object, I get an undefined method for the_post_object

Comment: the_post_object is the reference to the post you are generating the url for.  Replace the_post_object with the variable you are using in your method.

Comment: there isn't much more that can be done without more information... meaning the contents of routes.rb, the contents of the controllers in questions, and the contents of the models in question.

Comment: Hi, thanks again for the help. I've created a new question in hopes of tracking down this issue and provided the routes and controller/model http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5684027/rails-how-to-pass-a-posts-url-in-an-after-commit-method

Answer (score 0):

```
def twitter_share(post) 
  twitter.update("#{post.title}, #{post.content}")
end
```

You are passing a Post into the user.twitter_share method.